# Read value from config and return function

Tags: beginner, go

I’ve the following function which should be run in production
I read some config If valid add the runner otherwise just return,
the function is working!
Is there a cleaner/better way to do it in go? error handling...

https://play.golang.org/p/QcU9YHDXo36

```
func (z *zmp) Add(val string, runner Runner) {
    vmap := viper.GetStringMap(val)
    if len(vmap) > 0 {
        if val, ok := configs["active"]; ok {
            if !val.(bool) {
                log.info(“not valid”)
                return
            }
        }
    }
    z.Add(runner)
}
```

Comment: Also: using viper, I'd not bother with manually checking my own map, doing all the type assertions etc... I'd use `viper.SetDefault(key, values)`, where values can be a map, or a single value. I would also avoid relying on `map[string]interface{}` as much as possible, in favour of dedicated config types with `json` or `yaml` tags instead.